# Is there a way you can get rid of a border to a button in CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, border

I am working in HTML and CSS and I am trying to make a button. However, the button has a border that deviates from the website prototype. I have tried Googling around to no prevail.

[This is the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si56I.png)

This is the code I used (CSS)

````
    height: 50px;
    width: 132px;
    right: 874px;
    top: 610px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Noto Sans JP;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: none;
}```
````

Comment: Could you please add website prototype css applied to button as image doesn't give full idea.  I think you can use border:0 ! important; to remove the border. I also see some fixed height applied to button in image

Comment: Can you give more css and html?

Answer (score 1):

Add `border: none;` to your CSS `class`/`id` like this:

```css
.my-btn-class {
  border: none;
}
```

It will remove all of your button borders.